# Absolute value of expected value

Tags: expected-value, variance, covariance, bivariate-distributions

Given $(A_1,A_2)$ to be the bivariate random variable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with mean $0$ and cov($A_1,A_2)$ $= -1.05$ and $Var(Z_1) = Var(Z_2) = 1.05$.

How do I find the expected value of $E(|A_1A_2|)$? Progress: So far, I obtained $cov(A_1,A_2) = E(A_1A_2)-E(A_1)E(A_2) = E(A_1A_2) = -1.05$, given that mean of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is $0$.

However, is $|E(XY)| = E(|XY|)$?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: For an arbitrary random variable $Z$, we have $\vert E(Z)\vert \leq E(\vert Z\vert)$, just by writing down the integral definition of expectation.

Comment: @podiki so does that mean $E(|A_1A_2|) = 1.05$?

Comment: It means that $E(\vert A_1 A_2\vert) \geq 1.05$.

Comment: @podiki is there a way to find the exact value for $E(|A_1A_2|)$?